# Enable/Disable/Change Log Level for each Proxy in WSO2

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm looking for a way to enable/disable or change log level (Error, Info, Debug) of a log mediator for a specific proxy in WSO2, like in OSB. Is there any way to do it?
I know it is possible to do it at global level, but I wonder how it works for each proxy or even for each log mediator.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try per-service logging. See [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Per-Service+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this solution. However, do you know if is there any feature to enbl/dsbl or change logs severity level  like in OSB?